# pandas ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSV file that I'm comparing and returning only the columns side by side that have different values. So if one value is empty in one of the columns the code will through a error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

```
import pandas as pd


df1=pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')




def process_df(df):
    res = df.set_index('Country').stack()
    res.index.rename('Column', level=1, inplace=True)
    return res

df1 = process_df(df1)
df2 = process_df(df2)
mask = (df1 != df2) & ~(df1.isnull() & df2.isnull())
df3 = pd.concat([df1[mask], df2[mask]], axis=1).rename({0:'From', 1:'To'}, axis=1)
print(df3)
```

My current output without missing values :

```
                      From       To
Country      Column                  
Bermuda     1980    0.00793    0.00093
            1981    0.00687    0.00680
            1986    0.00700    1.00700
Mexico      1980    3.72819    3.92819
```

If some values are missing I just want a empty cell, like the example below :

```
                       From       To
Country      Column                  
Bermuda     1980    0.00793    0.00093
            1981    0.00687             <--- Missing value
            1986    0.00700    1.00700
Mexico      1980    3.72819    3.92819
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the indexes don't match...  As a simplified example (note that if you pass an empty element (`''`) into `df1` instead of, say, the `[4]` element it produces the same result):

```
In [21]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1], [4]])

In [22]: df1
Out[22]: 
   0
0  1
1  4
```

Using the same DF structure but changing the index...

```
In [23]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3], [2]], index=[1, 0])

In [24]: df2
Out[24]: 
   0
1  3
0  2
```

Now to compare...

```
In [25]: df1[0] == df2[0]
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

To prove out the index issue - recast `df2` without the reverse index...

```
In [26]: df3 = pd.DataFrame([[3], [2]])

In [27]: df3
Out[27]: 
   0
0  3
1  2
```

And the resulting comparison:

```
In [28]: df1[0] == df3[0]
Out[28]: 
0    False
1    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

#### The Fix

You'll have to reindex one of the `df`'s - like so (this is using "sortable" index - so more challenging for a more complex multi-index):

```
In [44]: df2.sort_index(inplace=True)

In [45]: df1[0] == df2[0]
Out[45]: 
0    False
1    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

If you can provide the CSV data, we could give it a try with a multi index...

#### Multi-Index

The `.sort_index()` method has a `level=` attribute that can be passed.  You can pass an [int or level name or list of ints or list of level names](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index).  So you could do something like:

```
df2.sort_index(level='level_name', inplace=True)

# as a list of levels... it will all depend on your original df index

levels = ['level_name1', 'level_name2]
df2.sort_index(level=levels, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Country 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985
Bermuda  0.0068 0.00727 0.00971 0.00752 0.00741
Canada 9.6947 9.58952 9.20637 9.18989 9.78546 10.15278
Greenland 0.00791 0.00746 0.00722 0.00505 0.00799 0.00714
Mexico 3.92819 4.11969 4.33477 4.06414 4.18464 4.42001
Saint Pierre and Miquelon 0.0022 0.00221 0.00203 0.00221 0.00216 0.00191
United States 78.12376 76.1694 73.15332 73.03603 77.02972 76.7898
Antarctica 0.00213 0.00213 0.00212 0.00213 0.0027 0.00304
Antigua and Barbuda 0.00598 0.00531 0.00711 0.00415 0.0047 0.00461
Argentina 1.64042 1.59706 1.67295  1.83705 1.74194

Comment: @James, Actually - can you provide links to the actual csv files (doesn't have to be your actual data) that work with your code to produce your output and error - you can use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/?landing=dbv2), [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/), [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/) or [Mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/) to host the files and then you can post the link here.